# Altium via template shows vias which are not in the PCB

Tags: altium, via

Under the via templates it shows there are 5 vias under the name, v45h20m0mx(1). But they are  not visible in the PCB. As you can see in the following image they are not visible in the bottom pane (highlighted in green) either.

On there other hand I cannot delete these either.

If someone knows a method get these deleted it would be a great help.

[image]

Comment: This question is only about a software issue, but not about any aspect of PCB design. It would be better suited in the official Altium forums.